# Proguard library and method warnings

Tags: java, android, proguard

Despite of trying various other methods, 3 of the existting warning doesnt seem to brush off..

```
Library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient implements program class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient 
The method `void com.google.android.gms.iid.MessengerCompat.<init>(android.os.IBinder)` does not type check and will be assumed to be unreachable.  
Library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient implements program class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
```

the above 3 warnings are consistent.
my current proguard file is as below :

```
-dontwarn java.nio.file.Files
-dontwarn java.nio.file.Path
-dontwarn java.nio.file.OpenOption
-dontwarn org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement

-keep class com.google.android.gms.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**

-keep class javax.servlet.ServletContextListener
-dontwarn javax.servlet.ServletContextListener

-keep  class com.google.firebase.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.google.firebase.**

-dontwarn org.apache.**
-keep class org.apache.http.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.apache.http.**
```

BUild.gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.tbg.www.thebutterflycorner"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 14
        versionName "14.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    }
}
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}

android {
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.1.0'
    implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:4.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.0.0'
    implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation files('libs/CircleImageView-master/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar')
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.msayan:tutorial-view:v1.0.10'
    implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.30.4'
    implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-gson:1.30.4'

    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'

    implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.12'
    implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6'
    implementation 'id.zelory:compressor:2.1.0'

    implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.2.0@aar'


}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

android manifest.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.tbg.www.thebutterflycorner">

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".ResultActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".SignInActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".ContactActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".CouponActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".ShareActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".MenuActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".GameActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".ButterfluyActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".HelpActivity"></activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyAWNDycLjhOoXec18EuN6rW7vkzqGpbpjQ" />

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

i dont know what other details to add for stackoverflow to detect this as a valid question,
so here is a string of characters for you to ignore #.gitignore

Comment: Post your gradle and manifest.xml

Comment: @war_Hero done, please check

Comment: add these and run 
-keep class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient.** { *; }

Comment: you have version incompatiblity between apache HttpClient and AndroidHttpClient you should use the supported version