# I dont know how to fix these Warnings

Tags: java, android, warnings

this is the first warning

```
Library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient implements program class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
```

this is second warning

```
Missing classes detected while running R8. Please add the missing classes or apply additional keep rules that are generated in F:\Fa_24_11_time_3_43\fa_db_my\app\build\outputs\mapping\release\missing_rules.txt.
```

last warning

```
Missing class com.facebook.infer.annotation.Nullsafe$Mode (referenced from: 
com.facebook.ads.NativeAdBase)
Missing class com.facebook.infer.annotation.Nullsafe (referenced from: 
com.facebook.ads.NativeAdBase)
Missing class com.google.firebase.messaging.TopicOperation$TopicOperations (referenced from: 
void com.google.firebase.messaging.TopicOperation.<init>(java.lang.String, java.lang.String))
```

Kindly guide me on how to solve these warnings in my android java project

## Proguard file

```
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepclassmembers class * {
 @org.greenrobot.eventbus.Subscribe <methods>;
}
-keep enum org.greenrobot.eventbus.ThreadMode { *; }

   And if you use AsyncExecutor:
  -keepclassmembers class * extends 
  org.greenrobot.eventbus.util.ThrowableFailureEvent {
  <init>(java.lang.Throwable);


 }

   -keep public class * implements com.bumptech.glide.module.GlideModule
    -keep class * extends com.bumptech.glide.module.AppGlideModule {
 <init>(...);
  }
   -keep public enum com.bumptech.glide.load.ImageHeaderParser$** {
    **[] $VALUES;
     public *;
   }
 -keep class 
 com.bumptech.glide.load.data.ParcelFileDescriptorRewinder$
  InternalRewinder 
 {
   *** rewind();


   }
 -keep class com.google.ads.** # Don't proguard AdMob classes
  -dontwarn com.google.ads.**
   -dontwarn org.apache.commons.**
```

all proguard rules i don't know why it always shows me these warnings

Comment: Add the proper config in proguard file as per your project implementations, it will work for you.

Comment: check i update proguard rules

Comment: for your last warning official document https://github.com/facebook/fresco/issues/2598

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58831905/proguard-library-and-method-warnings

Comment: check this thread for your some warnings- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27986264/android-proguard-with-httpcore-and-httpmime-using-android-studio-and-gradle

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your app-level build.gradle (if not existing)

```
dependencies {
implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:6.+'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.0.5'
}
```

then rebuild your project.